# SwiftでiOSのバージョン制限を設定したい。

Tags: swift

アプリを立ち上げたときに、例えば「iOS8.0より古い場合はご利用出来ません。」のようなiOSのバージョン制限をかける場合の方法はございますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`UIDevice`クラスから、システム（OS）のバージョンを取得できます。

```
let device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
print(device.systemVersion) // ex. "9.0"
```

なお、プロパティ`systemVersion`の型は、`String`型で、整数値ではないので、ご注意。

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございました。